# To date should be greater than from date in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, datepicker

If I select the start date, it should display the end date greater than the start date by default. In my code if I select the start date, End date is set same as start date. Here is my code. Thanks in advance.

```js
  $("#StartDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    minDate: 0,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#EndDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
    }
  });

  $("#EndDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
      $("#StartDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
    }
  });
});
```

Expected Result : If I select the start date, it should display the end date greater than the start date by default.

Actual Result : If I select the start date, End date is set same as start date.

Comment: What datepicker are you using?

Comment: you can follow this : http://jsfiddle.net/shyamsunderfiddle/oq9hr80L/

Comment: @javith I've added one solution down, please try it and get back

Comment: @shyamzzp yes I am using currently..But actually what i need is ,the to date should be greater than from date ,Here we can select the to date same as from date

Comment: @msg Using Bootstrap

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution.try it out
IF to date is empty it will set to next date
IF from date > to date to date will be the same as from date

```js
$('#StartDate').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
 }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
    var to =new Date($("#EndDate").find("input").val());
    var from = e.date;
    if (from == "" || from == null) { $('#EndDate').datepicker('setStartDate', from) }
    else if ($("#EndDate").find("input").val() == "")
      {
        var nextdate = new Date(from);
        var tomorrow = new Date();
        tomorrow.setDate(nextdate.getDate() + 1);
        $('#EndDate').datepicker('setDate', tomorrow)
      }
    else if (from < to) {
     }
     else if (!from < to) {
         $('#EndDate').datepicker('setDate', e.date)
      }
});


            $('#EndDate').datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
            }).on('changeDate', function (e) {
                var from = new Date($("#StartDate").find("input").val());
                var to = e.date;
                if (to < from)
                {
                    $('#StartDate').datepicker('setDate', e.date)
                }
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

try it out and getback to me .Thank you

Comment: @JavithJ include your Html also in the question. let me try. above snippet is working for me.